# Node.js and Puppeteer Error: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT at

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I can't handle the error that occurs if the proxy server is down. Here is the code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const proxyChain = require('proxy chain');

async function getPic() {
     const proxiesList = [
         'http://208.70.77.222:1994',
     ];

     const oldProxyUrl = proxiesList[Math.floor(Math.random() * (proxiesList.length))];
     const newProxyUrl = await proxyChain.anonymizeProxy(oldProxyUrl);

     const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
         headless: false
         ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
         args: [
             `--proxy-server=${newProxyUrl}`,
             `--ignore-certificate-errors`,
             `--no-sandbox`,
             `--disable-setuid-sandbox`
         ]
     });
     const page = await browser.newPage();
     await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.43 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36OPR/94.0.0.0');

     await page.goto('https://siteURL.com/',{
         waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"
     });

     await page.waitForSelector('input[type="search"]');
     await page.type('input[type="search"]','pc programs', {delay:500} )
     await page.click('button[type="submit"]');
     await page.waitForSelector('.footer-wrap'); 

     await page.waitForSelector('.footer-wrap');

     await page.evaluate(() => new Promise((resolve) => {
         let scrollTop = -1;
         const interval = setInterval(() => {
             window.scrollBy(0, 100);
             if(document.documentElement.scrollTop !== scrollTop) {
                 scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                 return;
             }
             clearInterval(interval);
             resolve();
         }, 500);
     }));

     awaitpage.screenshot({path: 'scr.png'});
     await browser.close();
     console log('1')

};

setInterval(getPic,50000);
```

An error is thrown Error: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT at

Tried with try-catch:

```
async function restartableFunction() {
  try {
    getPic()
  } catch (c) {
    if (error.message === "Error: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT") {
      console.error(error);
      // wait for a set amount of time before restarting the function
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
      // restart the function
      await restartableFunction();
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

Doesn't help solve problem.I would like to restart the function again if an error occurs in order to set up a working proxy and the code will continue to work. I will be very grateful for your advice!

Comment: What is c argument in your catch block? (c)

Comment: Typo, here is the correct code  `catch (error)`

Comment: Even though there is an error, the restartableFunction never gets to the if block, it doesn't catch it, that's why it can't "restart" the call to getPic(). Also, the code throws different error messages, it's not always "Error: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT", have that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restartableFunction never catches the error because the getPic() is async and it evaluates to a Promise.

You need to await the getPic() in try block of repeatableFunction:

```
try {
  await getPic();
 }
```

Read more about it here https://itnext.io/error-handling-with-async-await-in-js-26c3f20bc06a

Comment: Thank you! This helped solve my problem.